# How to (elegantly) read a file whose columns have different types and store the columns appropriately?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, polymorphism, variant

I am learning about templates and wanted to solve the following tasks along the way: I would like to read a `csv` file whose columns have different types (`string`, `int`, etc.), store each column in a `vector`, and then access the vectors. Can somebody kindly point out how I can store the columns well?

For the time being, **one example** of a csv file the program might encounter looks like this:

```
first_column,second_column
int,string
1, line1
2, line2
```

The csv files will always have the column name in the first row, and the data types in the second row, followed by the actual data. However, the potential number of columns is unrestricted, as is its' ordering or its' types. Hence, **another example** might be

```
first_column,second_column,third_colum
string, double, string
foo, -19.8, mario
bar, 20.1, anna
```

Based on the second row, the program knows the datatype of the columns (it also knows the total number of columns from the first row) and it can allocate the appropriate memory.

I imagine the header file of the class solving the task looks as:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class ColumnarCSV {
   public:
    ColumnarCSV(std::string filename) {read_data(filename);}
    std::vector<std::string> get_names() { return column_names; }
    std::vector<std::string> get_types() { return column_types; }
    // pseudocode
    template <typename T>
    std::vector<T> get_column(std::string column_name) {
        return column;
    }  //
   private:
    void read_data(std::string filename);
    std::vector<std::string> column_names;
    std::vector<std::string> column_types;
    // storage for the columns;
};
```

The class `ColumnarCSV` is constructed with a `string` stating the location of the `CSV file`. Two public functions provide the column names and columns types, encoded in a `vector<string>`. The function `get_column` requires a column name and returns its' data. Please note that I do not know how to write this function. The return type can be different if necessary. Does somebody have an idea how to store the columns appropriately and the populate them at run-time depending on the column type?

*What I tried so far:*

1. *Inheritance*: I tried to work with a base class `BaseColumn` which contains a column name and datatype. The derived class `template <typename T>ActualColumn: public BaseColumn` contains the actual data. I wanted to access the data through a virtual function but learned that I cannot define virtual template functions.
2. *Std:Variant*: I was thinking of working with [Std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and specify all possible types of the columns. However, I thought that there must be a way without resorting to c++17 innovations.
3. *Create empty `vector<vector<T>>` for all contingencies:* A brute-force idea would be to equip `ColumnarCSV` with member of `vector<vector<T>>` for all data types I can think of and populate them at run time. While this completed its' job, the code was very convoluted.

Is there a better way to solve define the class `ColumnarCSV`?

Comment: Store all values as strings, and covert them to other types only when asked.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating the problem. You do not really need templates and definitely you dont need inheritance or any form of type erasure when you always have a `int` and a `string`. If one row corresponds to one "entry" in the file, all you need is a

```
struct entry { 
    int id;
    std::string x;
};
```

and an input operator

```
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, entry& e) {
    in >> e.id;
    in >> e.x;
    return in;
}
```

Now reading the entries is straightforward. To read a single line you do

```
std::ifstream file("file.name");
entry x;
file >> x;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed reply! Do you think this solution is also suitable when there are all kinds of datatypes? (`doubles`, `std::chrono`...)? Especially, when the programs at compile time doesn't know what csv it will see. Instead of a line which has `int`, `string` as a line, the program could read a line `string`, `double`, `string`.

Comment: @fabian what exactly do you mean with "all kinds" of datatypes? At what point do you know the types? Are they fixed? Only known at compile time? Only known at runtime? If you read from the file you need to know what types to read anyhow, so there is no advantage of using templates (you cannot deduce the types and you dont need a generic solution to read an `int` and a `std::string`)

Comment: This approach doesn't however work if the columns are re-ordered. The fact that there are headers implies that re-ordering is a possibility.

Comment: @eerorika I have to admit, i didnt really understand the question. Maybe I'll try too improve the answer later, dont have time now unfortunately.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818: I tried to say what @eerorika referred to: Whilst in the example about the csv file has two columns with `int`, `string`, the next csv file the program reads might have columns with `string`, `double`, `string,`, `int` columns. At compile time, I do not want to restrict what csv files the program might encounter.

Comment: @fabian then who chooses as what type the data should be interpreted? Is it the user of `ColumnarCSV` ? Is this decision made when reading the entry? When constructing the `ColumnarCSV` ? you could allow to call `get_entry<double>` when the data is actually a string, resulting in runtime errors. Or you could choose the types on contruction of a `ColumnarCSV<int,std::string>` that provides only the correct getters. I think your question needs some clarification: How/where do you want to specify the actual types of the columns?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 thanks for your reply! I apologize for the vague description and clarified the question: I added a second example of a file the program might encounter. I also said that when the program has read the second line of the file, it know the number of columns and their datatypes and should be able to allocate the appropriate storage. Is the question clear know? Do you have an idea how to tackle the problem?

Comment: @fabian I cannot do it now, but I will probably come back here later

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 thanks a lot. I'm curious and looking forward to it!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can store the data line by line as full `std::string`.

Knowing the types of the data, you will be able to easily convert the `std::string` into the real type (`std::string`, `int`, `double`, ...).
For example, if you have a `std::string` that is a double in reality, you can use `std::stod` to convert it.

---

I have made an example to be more clear. Consider the following `struct` to handle the data:

```
typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVec;

struct FileData
{
    StringVec col_names;
    StringVec type_names;
    StringVec data_lines;

    bool loadData(const std::string & file_path);
    bool getColumn(const std::string & col_name, StringVec & result);
};
```

The `typedef` is only here to simplify the code and make it more readable.

The method `loadData()` will read the file and store its content in the structure.
`col_names` being the list of columns names, `type_names` being the list of types and `data_lines` being the list of the read lines.

The method `getColumn()` writes in the `result` argument the content of the desired column given in the `col_name` argument.

Those two methods return of boolean which indicates if the operation was successfully performed (`true`) or if an error occured (`false`).

`loadData()` may return false if the given file could not be opened or if it is corrupted.
`getColumn()` may return false if the given column name does not exist.

A possible implementation of these methods could be:

```
#include <fstream>

// ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========

StringVec split(const std::string & s, char c)
{
    StringVec splitted;

    std::string word;
    for(char ch : s)
    {
        if((ch == c) && (!word.empty()))
        {
            splitted.push_back(word);
            word.clear();
        }
        else
            word += ch;
    }
    if(!word.empty())
        splitted.push_back(word);

    return splitted;
}
void removeExtraSpaces(std::string & word)
{
    while(!word.empty() && (word[0] == ' '))
        word.erase(word.begin());

    while(!word.empty() && (word[word.size()-1] == ' '))
        word.erase(word.end()-1);
}

// ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========

bool FileData::loadData(const std::string & file_path)
{
    bool success(false);

    std::ifstream in_s(file_path);
    if(in_s)
    {
        bool names_read(false);
        bool types_read(false);

        std::string line;
        while(getline(in_s, line))
        {
            if(!names_read) // first line
            {
                col_names = split(line, ',');

                if(col_names.empty())
                    return false; // FILE CORRUPTED

                for(std::string & word : col_names)
                    removeExtraSpaces(word);

                names_read = true;
            }
            else if(!types_read) // second line
            {
                type_names = split(line, ',');

                if(type_names.size() != col_names.size())
                {
                    col_names.clear();
                    type_names.clear();
                    return false; // FILE CORRUPTED
                }

                for(std::string & word : type_names)
                    removeExtraSpaces(word);

                types_read = true;
            }
            else // other lines
            {
                if(split(line, ',').size() != col_names.size())
                {
                    col_names.clear();
                    type_names.clear();
                    data_lines.clear();
                    return false; // FILE CORRUPTED
                }

                data_lines.push_back(line);
            }
        }

        in_s.close();
        success = true;
    }

    return success;
}
bool FileData::getColumn(const std::string & col_name, StringVec & result)
{
    bool success(false);

    bool contains(false);
    size_t index(0);
    while(!contains && (index < col_names.size()))
    {
        if(col_names[index] == col_name)
            contains = true;
        else
            ++index;
    }
    if(contains)
    {
        for(const std::string & line : data_lines)
        {
            std::string field(split(line, ',').at(index));
            removeExtraSpaces(field);
            result.push_back(field);
        }
        success = true;
    }

    return success;
}

// ========== ========== ========== ========== ==========
```

The functions `split()` and `removeExtraSpaces()` are defined to simplify the code (and make this example more readable).

From the user's side, this can be used as follows:

```
DataFile df;
bool loadSuccessful = df.loadData("data.txt"); // if true, df contains now the content of the file.
StringVec col;
bool columnFound = df.getColumn("col_name", col); // if true, col contains now the content of the desired column.
```

As you can see, very easy to use :)
I know that at this point you have a vector of `std::string` but as the structure contains the names of the real type of each columns, you can convert what you got into the real type.
Perhaps you can add a templated `convert()` method in the structure to make this imperceptible for the user.

---

I have made the tests with the following data files:

*data.txt:*

```
first_col, second_col
string, double
line1, 1.1
line2, -2.5
line3, 10.03
```

_other_data.txt:_

```
first_col, second_col, third_col
int, string, char
0, line1, a
5, line2, b
```

And it worked successfully for both.

---

I don't know if handling the data as `std::string` is elegant enough for you but I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and informative reply! Why did you decide to change the return type to `getColumn` to a boolean, if I may ask? Was that maybe more straightforward to do?

Comment: Before the code implementation, I have written the meaning of the returned booleans for each method, go check this out :) But to be concise, the boolean is used to know if the process has succeed or fail.